# ¿Cómo podría hacer que este 'NaN' sea un número?

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy intentando realizar una suma, y me encuentro con un output que me devuelve un `NaN`. No se como podría hacer que los valores sean números:

```js
function hacerSuma() {
  let res = 0;
  let resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");
  let numero1 = document.getElementById("numero1");
  let numero2 = document.getElementById("numero2");
  numero1 = parseFloat(numero1);
  numero2 = parseFloat(numero2);
  res = numero1 + numero2;
  resultado.textContent = res;
}
```

```html
<form id="formu1">
  <div>Escribe un numero: <input type="number" id="numero1" size="10" value=""></div>
  <div>Escribe otro numero: <input type="number" id="numero2" size="10" value=""></div>
</form>
<div><button id="suma" onclick="hacerSuma()">Click para sumar</button></div>
<div>Resultado: <output id="resultado"></output></div>
```

Comment: Te da `NaN` por que en ningún momento obtienes el valor del atributo `value` de cada `input`; prueba hacer esto: `numero1=parseFloat(numero1.value);
                    numero2=parseFloat(numero2.value);` y con eso ya te debe funcionar

Comment: Muchas gracias ! :)